# c++ make_shared<> with 2d array

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Using simple pointers when dealing with 2d array allocation is done by new in this way (suppose matrix 10x1000) :

```
double ** dPtr ;
dPtr = new  double*  [10] ;
    for( size_t i =0 ; i<10 ; i++ ){
         dPtr[i] = new double [1000] ;
    }
```

Now, when using smart pointers, we can define the matrix type (suppose using `shared_ptr`) as

```
std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<double[]>[]> dPtr ;
```

How is the correct syntax to perform the same allocation using `make_shared<>`?

Comment: Maybe using vectors would be  better.

Comment: I would just know how is the way ...

Comment: The `[]` can be thought of as a pointer so `shared_ptr<double[]>` is a shared pointer to a pointer. What you probably think you want is `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<double>>`.  What you actually should do is use a library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct translation of your code to `std::make_shared()` would look like this:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<double[]>[]> dPtr;
dPtr = std::make_shared<std::shared_ptr<double[]>>(10);
for( size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ){
     dPtr[i] = std::make_shared<double[]>(1000);
}
```

Which can be cleaned up a little further, eg:

```cpp
using double_ptr_1D = std::shared_ptr<double[]>;
using double_ptr_2D = std::shared_ptr<double_ptr_1D[]>;

double_ptr_2D dPtr = std::make_shared<double_ptr_1D>(10);
for( double_ptr_1D &elem : dPtr ){
     elem = std::make_shared<double[]>(1000);
}
```

Or even:

```cpp
using double_ptr_1D = std::shared_ptr<double[]>;

auto dPtr = std::make_shared<double_ptr_1D>(10);
for( auto &elem : dPtr ){
     elem = std::make_shared<double[]>(1000);
}
```

Now, that being said, array support was not added to `std::shared_ptr` until C++17, and not to `std::make_shared()` until C++20.  So, if you are using C++17 then you will have to construct your arrays manually using `new[]`, eg:

```cpp
using double_ptr_1D = std::shared_ptr<double[]>;
using double_ptr_2D = std::shared_ptr<double_ptr_1D[]>;

double_ptr_2D dPtr( new double_ptr_1D[10] );
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    dPtr[i] = double_ptr_1D( new double[1000] );
}
```

But, if you are using C++11 or C++14 then you are out of luck, as you won't be able to use `std::shared_ptr` for your arrays at all.  `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 onward has array support, as does `std::make_unique()` in C++14 onward, but `std::unique_ptr` does not have the reference-counting semantics that `std::shared_ptr` has.  If you really need that, you would have to implement your own reference counting manually.

Comment: Does this work for C++17? From reading here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0674r1.html and here: https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/08/17smallercpp17features.html (point 14), it seems that `make_shared` with arrays is a C++20 feature...

Answer (score 2):

I would not call new that many times, but instead allocate a large buffer a single time: `double* array = new double[10 * 1000];`. Of course this depends on what kind of data structure you want. A single buffer will have better cache locality and likely be much faster, but it depends on your requirements.

Also, what you are doing is having a `shared_ptr` to each row in the matrix - is that what you want? It would probably be better to have a single shared_ptr to managing the entire matrix:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<double[]> array (new double[10*1000]);
```

If you really want you can have a shared_ptr to each row also:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<double[]>[]> array2(
    new std::shared_ptr<double[]>[10]);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array2[i] = std::shared_ptr<double[]>(new double[1000]);
}
```

Comment: You can use `make_shared<T[]>(N)` instead of `shared_ptr<T>(new T[N])`. The OP did ask how to use `make_shared`.

Comment: Oh I misread. :/ but thanks. I will not update my answer seeing that you already show a solution